# Android Studio - Cannot resolve symbol 'progressBar' / Cannot resolve symbol 'layoutBg'

Tags: android, symbols

I'm trying to update my android app code but getting a lot of error warnings.

Anyone know what these should be renamed to?

Cannot resolve symbol 'progressBar'

Cannot resolve symbol 'layoutBg'

I did manage to rename the warning in one file to progressbar1 which
got rid of the error, but in other files the same error doesn't go away
when I rename it to progressbar1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, add a code and a layout. Your activity or fragment doesn't know where to find required ids in a layout. How do you refer to `progressBar`?

Comment: Also post the error stacktrace, you said renaming in one place fixed the problem meaning you may be having duplicate id issues a swell.